# Image hover working properly only on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, hover

I made a vertical image slider, every image is a link, when the image is hovered, a black "glass pane" with 0.4 opacity covers the image and displays some text. In fact the background is a transparent png

The problem is that it only shows correctly in google chrome.

- Opera: i see only the glass pane, but not the text over it
- Firefox: I don't see the glass pane, but i see the text over the glasspane only for the first 2 items, the third text is not shown, and the spacing between images is different from what Google Chrome and Opera are displaying
- IE: The spacing between images is different from what Google Chrome and Opera are displaying, and hover does nothing, no glass pane displayed and even no text displayed.

http://alessandroderoma.it/try/slider/

What is displayed in google chrome needs to be displayed in all other browsers.

However, this is the html code i'm using:

```
<div id="vertical_slideshowwrapper">
    <div class="vertical_slideshow" style="visibility: visible; overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 2; left: 0px; height: 489px;">
        <ul style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; list-style-type: none; z-index: 1; height: 4564px; top: -1956px;">
            <li style="overflow: hidden; float: none; width: 165px; height: 489px;">
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="images/1.png" border="0">
                    <div class="box"><p>Text 1</p></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="images/2.png" border="0">
                    <div class="box"><p>Text 2</p></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="images/3.png" border="0">
                    <div class="box"><p>Text 3</p></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="overflow: hidden; float: none; width: 165px; height: 489px;">
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="images/4.png" border="0">
                    <div class="box"><p>Text 4</p></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="images/5.png" border="0">
                    <div class="box"><p>Text 5</p></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="images/6.png" border="0">
                    <div class="box"><p>Text 6</p></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="overflow: hidden; float: none; width: 165px; height: 489px;">
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="images/7.png" border="0">
                    <div class="box"><p>Text 7</p></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="images/8.png" border="0">
                    <div class="box"><p>Text 8</p></div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_self">
                    <img src="images/9.png" border="0">
                    <div class="box"><p>Text 9</p></div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
    body{
        background-color:#000;
    }
    DIV#vertical_slideshowfooter { 
        display:block; 
        padding-top: 10px; 
        font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; 
        font-size: 8px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
    } 
    div#vertical_slideshowwrapper { 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        overflow: hidden; 
        margin: 0px auto;  
    } 
    .vertical_slideshow ul li { 
        list-style:none; 
        margin-bottom:1px; 
        display:block; 
    } 
    .vertical_slideshow li img { 
        margin-right: 5px; 
        margin-top:1px; 
        margin-bottom:1px; 
        width: 160px; 
        height: 162px; 
    } 

    body{
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-left:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-left:0px;
    }

    .box {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        margin-top: -163px;
        width: 160px;
        height: 163px;
        background-image: url(images/bg.png);
        background-position:0 0;
        text-indent:-99999px;
    }

    .box:hover {
        background-position:-160px 0;
        text-indent:0;
    }

    .box p{
        position:absolute;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
        bottom: -8px;
        right: 6px;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .box a, a:visited, a:hover{
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated

CSS validator results:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=alessandroderoma.it%2Ftry%2Fslider&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=it

Comment: Could do with a little tidy-up. You have multiple elements with id="box", which is invalid. Also, you have a couple of places in the CSS where a `<length>` type property has no units, e.g. #box { margin-top: -163; }, which is also incorrect.

Comment: check my link from w3c validator, i added measures unit on every length which was different from 0, Also changing from id="box" to class="box" has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As New Developer said, i added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of my HTML document, and it made my html output to be quite similar on all browsers, and made also the mouse over css to work with IE, but didn't solve my problem with Opera, the text over images was still not being displayed.
I googled a lot and i found that Opera enables text-indent only for `block` elements, but even adding

```
display: inline-block
```

to my `.box` elements didn't solve the problem, so i had to find a workaround.

I solved it using `padding` instead of `text-indent`:

```
.box {
    padding-left: 99999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box:hover {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

It worked, it's not a solution, but for me it's a good workaround.

Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 2):

Place below line top of your html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881015/1719369)

**EDIT**
I think there is a issue with `text-indent` in opera.
I can suggest you a answer.
initially make text color to **black** and when hover make it to **white**

```
.box {  
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -163px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 163px;
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
    background-position:0 0;
    color:black;        /*added*/
    }   


.box:hover {
    background-position:-160px 0;
    text-indent:0;
    color:white;    /*added*/
}
```

Comment: +1 it made mouseover to work with IE, but i'm still not seeing the text with Opera

Comment: Sorry I don't have opera to test. But I think adjusting `bottom: -8px;` value may help you.

Comment: Here a screenshot of all the browser listed before: http://alessandroderoma.it/try/slider/rect3922.png this was taken before adding the doctype rule, opera is the only one that has problems showing my text

Comment: Did you tried to change `bottom: -8px;` value in the `.box p{`. (make it +18)

Comment: Only the text is not visible now? How can I help you without having the browser. I think your text is there (below the image) and it is cover from the next image. just to make sure change your `right: 6x;` to -50. so you can see it.

Comment: -50?? with -50 i'm putting the text near the image, and not over it!

Comment: i am just telling to confirm that text is not covering from below image.

Comment: Oh, ok, i didn't understand, however i can't see the text even with right:-50px

Comment: Black text and then white? i have to hide my text, the image behind the text can be of any color, if i have a blank image i will see it.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion:
 other browsers don't support some css tag maybe you might want to check it out
 for IE http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html
 have you look onto this link http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: I know, but i think i'm using pretty common css, IE is a particular case, but i think it should work for opera and firefox, but in fact it doesn't work and i don't understand why

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>  <---- no like this  in your http://alessandroderoma.it/try/slider/

Answer (score -1):

You can use background color instead of image. Because you can set the transparency of background color like your image. Put the caption of your slider into a div class and write down the following code for your desired output.

.your_css_class
{
   background: #FDF7A6; /* Set your background color * /
   opacity: 0.5;/* Set opacity */
}

Also remember to set the width, height and position of your div class. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: With a png i'm sure i have my background opacity, with your code i'm not, some browser may not support this rule.